# Laravel Mix: compile Sass into .css and min.css

Tags: webpack, sass, laravel-mix

I've run my head against the wall here.

For my project, I would like Laravel Mix/webpack to compile an `.scss`-file into two files, a regular, un-minified (expanded or nested) `.css`-file, and a minified (compressed) `.min.css`-file, so I essentially have both files.

I've tried with:

```
mix.sass('src', 'output')
   .copy('output.css', 'output.min.css')
   .minify('output.min.css');
```

However, this results in an error because the `.css`-file wasn't compiled.

I know Laravel Mix minifies when running `npm run production` but I'm interested in two files, not just the one `production` compiles to.

Is there any way to do this, without modifying the whole webpack config?

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer by messing with a few things, and came to the conclusion that I'm not going to use Laravel Mix's `production`-script for this. I couldn't find a way for Laravel Mix not to minify the regular CSS when running `npm run production`, however, `production` was needed for `minify()` to work, as it doesn't minify if the environment is `development`.

So I pulled in a package that minify on command. This is where `minifier()` comes to the rescue.

`npm install --save-dev minifier`

Then my `webpack.mix.js` looks like this:

```js
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
let minifier = require('minifier');

mix.sass('src/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/', {
    outputStyle: 'nested'
});

mix.then(() => {
    minifier.minify('public/css/app.css')
});
```

The `mix.then()` is triggered when webpack finishes building, and `.minify()` will automagically create a new file called `app.min.css`.

Then when I run `npm run dev`, my Sass will be compiled in nested format, and it will also be minified. Not the most elegant solution but this is the best I could come up with.

And hey, if it's stupid but it works, it's not stupid. I mean, a CPU is literally a rock that we tricked into thinking[¹](https://twitter.com/daisyowl/status/841802094361235456).

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Mix/Webpack has some prebuild scripts in package.json file.
Keep it like:

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

and when you want to minify css do `npm run production` in console, otherwise `npm run development`.

*EDIT*: If you want to do both streams sassed and minified do it separately:

```
mix.sass('src', 'output');
mix
.sass('src', 'output')
.minify('output.min.css');
```

Comment: I'm quite aware of how the `npm` scripts work. So I don't think you read my question fully. I want to keep the un-minified `.css`-file and generate a minified `.min.css`-file aswell. Not just the one, minified file when I run `npm run production`.

I have edited the question to make it more clear what I want to do. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Okay, I got confused. Now my answer may help.

Comment: No problem, and thanks. However, `copy()` throws an error saying the file or directory doesn't exist, even if I seperate the two like you suggested. I have even tried with absolute paths, but alas. So I have made an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/852).

Comment: Okay, forgive me. What if you erase copy? That's why I put two mix actions.

Comment: Then Laravel Mix whines about duplicates :)
Trust me, running two `mix.sass` was the very first thing I tried as it would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this-

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/bootstrap.scss', 'public/css');
```

But shortly check the name bootstrap.scss in file.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but i think this might help:

```
/**
 * Tested over Laravel Mix V6 
 */
//If your in development, normally you compile the original css. You can run (npx mix watch) command then start your edits
if(!mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.js( 'src/app.js', 'dist/' )
    .sass('src/output.scss', 'assets/css/output.css');
}

//Then this will run only on production, which will minify the output
if(mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.js( 'src/app.js', 'dist/' )
    .sass('src/output.scss', 'assets/css/output.min.css');
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).